# Deploy Multiple Content Types

Tags: content-type

I have 30 CTs that I want to add to 20+ Site Collections. I have found a PowerShell script that can deploy a CT with a FIELD and parent but was after doing this in one go or just changing the URL variable and then running the script once for every SC. here is the PS...

```
$site = get-spsite $url

$web = $site.openweb()

$ctypeName = “myName”

$ctypeParent = $web.availablecontenttypes["Document"]

$ctype = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType($ctypeParent, $web.contenttypes, $ctypeName)

$web.contenttypes.add($ctype)

$web.fields.add(“myField”, ([Type]“Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType”)::Text, $false)

$field = $web.fields.getfield(“myField”)

$fieldLink = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink($field)

$ctype.fieldlinks.add($fieldLink)

$ctype.Update()

$web.Dispose()

$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: with a filed means? and what exact problem are you facing?

Comment: FIELD, sorry. My problem is that I want to do this in a quick automated way instead of manually adding all 30 CTs to 20+ site collections

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to store the names of all the sitecollections like this

```
$siteCollectionUrls = @("siteUrl1", "siteUrl2", "siteUrl3")
for ($i=0; $i -lt $siteCollectionUrls .length; $i++) {
    $currentSiteUrl = $array[$i]
    # put logic for adding content types here
}
```

Similarly you can do kind of the same for iterating the content types in a inner loop for each site collection

Comment: Thanks both for your help. just realised I have an issue of assigning them to libraries not deploying them as we have a content hub